# Cannot read the txt file

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a txt file, which stores a matrix. But each time I execute, it reads all values 0. For reading the txt file I used the following code:

```
using matrix = valarray< valarray<double> >;
matrix tt(std::valarray<double>(0.0, 4), 5);

fstream inFile;
inFile.open("/home/tech/filename.txt", fstream::in);
    
    if (inFile.is_open())
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
                inFile >> tt[i][j];

            }


        }
   inFile.close();
    }
```

I am using OMNet++ 5.5.1 in ubuntu.

Would anyone please suggest a solution? Thank you.

Comment: Your file path looks strange, : `/home/filename.txt` usually under linux you store files in your account folder like `/home/user_name_here/filename.txt`, otherwise you risk problems with permissions etc.

Comment: @marcinj, I have updated the file path now. But it is still not working.

Comment: Can you share the content of your file?

Comment: What is the type of `tt` ?

Comment: @marcinj, I used ```using matrix = valarray< valarray<double> >;```
```matrix tt(std::valarray<double>(0.0, 4), 5);```

Comment: @11187162: As a SO rule we prefer code examples of "why isn't this working?" to be complete, self-contained, readily compilable examples. Your example might only be missing a couple of lines to be self-contained, but these few lines might contain the actual problem (as the code you are presenting here looks fine on its own). You might want to add some debug output after `if (inFile.is_open())` to show that your loops are actually running, because as it stands you wouldn't know either way.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your array contain `double` type elements, you can add elements from the text file to your std::valarray as follows. The below program reads double from input.txt and if there is some invalid entry in the file lets say there is some string then it will skip that string and read the next value and only if that value is valid(double) it will put it into the valarray.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <valarray>
int main()
{
    
    std::string line;

    std::ifstream inFile("input.txt");
   
   std::valarray<std::valarray<double>> arr (std::valarray<double>(0.0, 4), 5);
   
    if(inFile)
    {
        double i = 0;//this variable will be used to add element into the array
        int currentRow = 0;
        int currentColumn = 0;
        while(getline(inFile, line, '\n'))        
        {
            
            
            
            std::istringstream s(line);
            
            //take input(from s to i) and then checks stream's eof flag status
            while(s >> i || !s.eof()) {
                //check if either failbit or badbit is set
                if(s.fail()) 
                {
                    //clear the error state to allow further operations on s
                    s.clear();
                    std::string temp;
                    s >> temp;
                    continue;
                 }
                else 
                {
                    
                    arr[currentRow][currentColumn] = i;
                    
                    ++currentColumn;
                    
                    if(currentColumn >= 4)
                    {
                        currentColumn = 0;
                        ++currentRow;
                        
                    }
                    //break when we have filled all rows
                    if(currentRow >=5)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                                     
                    
                }

}
            
            
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"file could not be read"<<std::endl;
    }
    inFile.close();
    
     for(int i = 0; i<5; ++i)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<4; ++j)
        {
            std::cout<<arr[i][j]<<std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output of the above program can be checked [here](https://onlinegdb.com/bcuZLLlOM).

Comment: This shows a different program, and doesn't actually answer the question (which uses `std::valarray` as per OP's comment)...?

Comment: @DevSolar The OP hasn't mentioned that he/she used `std::valarray` in his asked question. He said it in the comment which i didn't read. Also he could modify this program very easily to work with `std::valarray` instead of `std::array`.

Comment: @DevSolar We only need to change `double arr[20] = {0.0};` to `std::valarray<double> arr (20);` to use `std::valarray` instead of `array`. And everything else remains the same. And other constraints(that i explained in the answer) still apply. I demonstrated how it can be done fo 1D case. Now it is on the OP to extend it to work with 2D cases. Also the OP should have mentioned in his question that matrix is using `std::valarray` and not built in array.

Comment: @DevSolar The OP didn't even mention(originally) that what type of elements(double, int etc) `matrix` holds. If you provide wrong information you get a wrong answer.

Comment: No offense intended, but OP is even newer to SO than you are, and he amended his question 20 minutes before you posted your answer... And you amended your answer after I posted my comment, so where's the problem? I still have reservations with this answer though. OP's code was *clearly* two-dimensional even before the amend, and your answer still isn't. And you're using `break` and `continue` which should not really be necessary here. I still think that you aren't really answering the question (poor and in its current form un-answerabe as it is).

Comment: @DevSolar I clearly mentioned in my answer that "You can modify this program to work with 2D arrays" . The point is to show how it can be done for one case so that he/she can learn from it.  Regarding the timing of the answer(by me) and OP's ammendment, the starting `two` statements in his code snippet was edited after i posted both my answer and comment. And most importantly he/she still hasn't shared the content of the input file named filename.txt. His question cannot be fully answered simply because his question has **incomplete information** .

Comment: The starting two statements in OP's code snippet were from a comment OP posted well before your answer. Instead of having an argument with me, you could have improved your answer accordingly in the meantime. If you feel the Q is lacking, you can vote to close as incomplete (which I have done after OP failed to respond to a query for a more complete example). Still the point stands: Showing a completely different program, for a different case no less, is not a good answer.

Comment: @DevSolar I was already working on modifying my 1D case to work for 2D case which i have added now in my answer.